# TinyMCE only showing 2 Colors in the ColorPicker instead of 3

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

TinyMCE backcolor module displays only 2 colors out of 3 in color_map

I'm integrating the backcolor module from TinyMCE in my project and using the **color_map** configuration to provide a quick selection of specific colors that are important for our application. However, I'm encountering an issue where only 2 colors are displayed in the dropdown instead of the intended 3.

Here's a visual representation of the issue:
Screenshot of TinyMCE showing 2 colors
[image]

Below are the relevant parts of my configuration:

TS-File:

```
modules = {
    base_url: '/tinymce',
    suffix: '.min',
    content_css: environment.cssUrl,
    content_style: 'body { padding: 20px; }',
    language: this.translateService.currentLang,
    branding: false,
    menubar: false,
    link_context_toolbar: false,
    resize: false,
    statusbar: false,
    skin: 'oxide',
    plugins: 'autolink lists link image table',
    toolbar:
      'drpdwnHeading bold bullist numlist indent outdent table link image backcolor | style_formats',
    color_map: [
      '#FDECD9',
      '#FFDCDC',
      '#E8E4E4'
    ],
    setup: this.editorCustomSetup,
};
```

HTML:

```
<editor [init]="modules"></editor>
```

How can I ensure all 3 colors are displayed in the backcolor dropdown? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`color_map` config](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#color_map) is slightly odd in that although it is specified as an array, it's actually expecting a map of color/name pairs rather than just the color values.

So, you should be specifying an array of six values, with a name for each colour (perhaps one with a semantic meaning for your application), e.g.

```
...
    color_map: [
      '#FDECD9', 'Heading',
      '#FFDCDC', 'Sub-heading',
      '#E8E4E4', 'Footnote'
    ],
...
```

Your current config is failing because it's taking `#FFDCDC` as the name for the first color `#FDECD9`, and `undefined` as the name for your third color `#E8E4E4`, so you'll only see the first and third colors in the menu.